# firebase.database() is not a function, using current firebase real time database library

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I'm trying to build a database that takes a form and inputs variables into a real time db, using firebase. This is the error I get:

> index.html:31 Uncaught TypeError: firebase.database is not a function 
>   at index.html:31

This is the code:

```
    function writeData() {
        dbRefObject.set({
            name: document.getElementById("name").value, 
            mail: document.getElementById("mail").value
        });
    }
```

The libraries are initialized:

```
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.11.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script>
 var firebaseConfig = {
apiKey: "AIzaSyDiiNKj-35XZWYJcYonBsjR0hGLzWZg7cs",
authDomain: "userdata-6467c.firebaseapp.com",
databaseURL: "https://userdata-6467c.firebaseio.com",
projectId: "userdata-6467c",
storageBucket: "userdata-6467c.appspot.com",
messagingSenderId: "390942612693",
appId: "1:390942612693:web:0692607d98edf2f2"
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
   firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

Any ideas would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Have you initialised Firebase?

Comment: Have you added the cdn links of firebase libraries? If yes, then can you also post those links?

Comment: Please edit the question to show how you added the Firebase libraries to the page where this code is running.

Answer (score 2):

Try read this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase

In your code, you can access Firebase using:

```
var firebase = require('firebase');
firebase.intializeApp({
    apiKey: '<your-api-key>',
    authDomain: '<your-auth-domain>',
    databaseURL: '<your-database-url>',
    storageBucket: '<your-storage-bucket>'
});
```

If you setup a Service Account via Permissions in the new Google Firebase dashboard go here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/server/setup#add_the_sdk

Comment: Is that using node?